# JavaScript: Retrieve Only Minute From Server Generated Date().toTimeString()

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

My server WebSocket app is sending the client the time in the following format:

```
client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
```

And the JavaScript client is receiving it like so:

```
01:32:13 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
```

I would like to retrieve only the MINUTE and nothing else. How may I do so?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes(); see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log("01:32:13 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)".split(":")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().getMinutes()` to return `32` in your example.

So your code would be:

```
client.send(new Date().getMinutes());
```

If you want to send it as a string instead of an integer use:

```
client.send(new Date().getMinutes().toString());
```

Comment: The server timezone could be different than the client's timezome so this would be erroneous.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the getMinutes() function would be executed server-side, no? Hence the client would always receive the server-side time as requested.